# Magento 2 : Payment Method is Hidden in Admin When Creating Manual Order

Tags: admin, orders, payment-methods, magento2.2.2

Recently I upgraded to Magento 2.2.2 and tried to create a test order on my site via admin.

All goes fine until selecting the payment method. I've enabled Purchase Order as a payment method, and prior to the 2.2.2 upgrade, this was selectable in the order screen.

The option label appears but the input box doesn't.

[image: missing input box for payment method]

I checked the console for errors, and none are shown. So I looked for the input field itself and noticed that the fieldset element has a style applied - style="display: none" but it's not in the admin stylesheet, it's applied directly to the fieldset element.

[image: hidden input field applied style]

This means I can't place the order, as the field is required... If I disable the "hidden" style in the console I can see the form error when trying to submit the order.

[image: hidden field error]

Can anyone advise how to fix this?

Comment: Have you try to enable other payment method as well, and then try to create order?

Comment: Hi @DhirenVasoya yes I enabled "cash on delivery" and that allows me to choose from either payment option, so I can now process the order. Odd that it doesn't work with just the one method though?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in magento 2.2.x and has a github task assigned to it.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11380

Comment: Means Magento2 can't provide to add the payment method in the admin panel.